# Global installation of ExpressJS isn't working

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

So I am simply learning NodeJs and came across the express module and so I can use it whenever I added `-g` so that it was global but now I cant access it. Instead of my program running I am greeted with `at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*****\Documents\NodeJS Coding\Examples\Express_Example\app.js:1:17)`.

I have tried installing without `-g` and that works but the global installation doesn't.

Here is my NodeJS code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.listen("3000");
```

Comment: What exactly you are facing?

Comment: Paste your package.json file

Comment: @xMayank Basically its saying there is no such module

Comment: Show your package.json file

Comment: @xMayank https://justpaste.it/54a5x

Comment: do `npm install` and install your dependencies then run your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should not** install express globally.

Express is a core dependency of your application. Users who might use your application and install its dependencies would not be aware of the express dependency that you installed globally on **your** machine.

For the same reason, if you ever wanted to migrate your application to a different system, you would have to additionally install express globally, even though it's a dependency of your application.

You should always install core dependencies as normal dependencies. Only miscellaneous packages (e.x. project generators, etc) should be installed globally, since users who install your application would not need to use them.